# Playing MIDI instruments in Java

Tags: java, audio, music

This program offers 8 notes C, D, ..., A, B, C on keyboard keys 1, 2, ..., 8. Also, by typing Left or Right, you can cycle over MIDI instruments.

**KeyboardPiano.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.music;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.sound.midi.Instrument;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.midi.Soundbank;
import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class KeyboardPiano {

    private static final String APP_TITLE = "Keyboard Piano";

    private final JFrame frame = new JFrame(APP_TITLE);
    private final Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    private Synthesizer synthesizer;
    private final MidiChannel[] midiChannels;
    private final Instrument[] instruments;
    private int instrumentIndex = 0;

    KeyboardPiano() {
        try {
            synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
            synthesizer.open();
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }   

        this.midiChannels = synthesizer.getChannels();

        Soundbank bank = synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank();

        synthesizer.loadAllInstruments(bank);


        this.instruments = synthesizer.getAvailableInstruments();
        synthesizer.loadAllInstruments(synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank());
        synthesizer.getChannels()[0].programChange(instrumentIndex);

        System.out.println("[STATE] MIDI channels: " + midiChannels.length);
        System.out.println("[STATE] Instruments: " + instruments.length);
    }

    private void init() {   
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        canvas.addKeyListener(new KeyboardPianoListener());
        canvas.setFocusable(true);
        canvas.requestFocus();
    }

    private void show() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyboardPiano keyboardPiano = new KeyboardPiano();
        keyboardPiano.init();
        keyboardPiano.show();
    }

    private final class KeyboardPianoListener implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getExtendedKeyCode();
            int noteNumber = -1;

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_1: {
                    noteNumber = 60;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_2: {
                    noteNumber = 62;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_3: {
                    noteNumber = 64;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_4: {
                    noteNumber = 65;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_5: {
                    noteNumber = 67;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_6: {
                    noteNumber = 69;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_7: {
                    noteNumber = 71;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_8: {
                    noteNumber = 72;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: {
                    if (instrumentIndex == 0) {
                        instrumentIndex = instruments.length - 1;
                    } else {
                        instrumentIndex--;
                    }

                    synthesizer.getChannels()[0].programChange(instrumentIndex);
                    System.out.println("Switched to " + 
                                       instruments[instrumentIndex].getName());
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: {
                    if (instrumentIndex == instruments.length - 1) {
                        instrumentIndex = 0;
                    } else {
                        instrumentIndex++;
                    }

                    synthesizer.getChannels()[0].programChange(instrumentIndex);
                    System.out.println("Switched to " + 
                                       instruments[instrumentIndex].getName());
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (noteNumber != -1) {
                midiChannels[0].noteOn(noteNumber, 600);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getExtendedKeyCode();
            int noteNumber = -1;

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_1: {
                    noteNumber = 60;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_2: {
                    noteNumber = 62;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_3: {
                    noteNumber = 64;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_4: {
                    noteNumber = 65;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_5: {
                    noteNumber = 67;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_6: {
                    noteNumber = 69;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_7: {
                    noteNumber = 71;
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_8: {
                    noteNumber = 72;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (noteNumber != -1) {
                midiChannels[0].noteOff(noteNumber, 600);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any critique much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Repetition, specially when it occurs with switch cases is both bad for you and for your code. The `switch (keyCode)` is present two times in your code and all it does (almost) is just to **map** an integer. And I bolded map because that if that is what you want to do then we can use the [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to specify the note number that a key matches to.

```
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mapNotes = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

KeyboardPiano() {
    try {
        synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synthesizer.open();
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }   

    mapNotes.put(KeyEvent.VK_1, 60);
    mapNotes.put(KeyEvent.VK_2, 62);
    mapNotes.put(KeyEvent.VK_3, 64);
    mapNotes.put(KeyEvent.VK_4, 65);
    mapNotes.put(KeyEvent.VK_5, 67);
    mapNotes.put(KeyEvent.VK_6, 69);
    mapNotes.put(KeyEvent.VK_7, 71);
    mapNotes.put(KeyEvent.VK_8, 72);
    //...
}
```

And then use this same map

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getExtendedKeyCode();
    int noteNumber = -1;

    if(mapNotes.containsKey(keyCode)){
        noteNumber = mapNotes.get(keyCode);
    }
    //...
 }
```

The switch statment in `keyPressed` can also be simplified because there is common code. The following code is executed in both left and right key press.

```
synthesizer.getChannels()[0].programChange(instrumentIndex);
System.out.println("Switched to " + 
                 instruments[instrumentIndex].getName());
```

With everything put togheter the `keyPressed`becomes the following:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getExtendedKeyCode();
    int noteNumber = -1;

    if(mapNotes.containsKey(keyCode)){
        noteNumber = mapNotes.get(keyCode);
    }else{
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: {
                if (instrumentIndex == 0) {
                    instrumentIndex = instruments.length - 1;
                } else {
                    instrumentIndex--;
                }
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: {
                if (instrumentIndex == instruments.length - 1) {
                    instrumentIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    instrumentIndex++;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        synthesizer.getChannels()[0].programChange(instrumentIndex);
        System.out.println("Switched to " + 
                           instruments[instrumentIndex].getName());
    }

    if (noteNumber != -1) {
        midiChannels[0].noteOn(noteNumber, 600);
    }
}
```